# Tablesorter and saving sort

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table with some information. 
At first time it is generate from php-script and then every n-seconds check database.

Then I've installed tablesorter plugin. It's okay, but now, after getting information from database(if table was sorted by several fields) sort "configuration" resets.

So I've found some information about saveSort plugins, download `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` include it into my project. In plugin's documentation I've found some instruction like `how to`.

```
$("table").tablesorter({
   widgets: ["saveSort"]
});
```

But it doesn't fix my problem. After getting results the saved sort resets.

So, here is the code of my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("table").tablesorter({
        widgets: ["saveSort"]
    });

    function get_op(){

       var dataSend = "to teh mooon";

       jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST", 
           url: "get_url",
           dataType:"html",
           data:dataSend,

           success:function(response){
               $("#recent_op tbody").html(response);
               $("#recent_op").trigger("update");

           },
           error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              $("#recent_operations").html(thrownError);
           }
       });

     }
  setInterval(function(){get_op()}, 10000);

});
```

Here is simple table that I used.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter" id = "recent_op">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header # <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
             ....
             </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
             ....
           </tr>
                    ....
            <tr>
              <td>Body</td>
               ....
             </tr>
       </tbody>
  </table>
```

So, no errors, everythings from tutorial, but it doesn't work good. I think I'm use this widget in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The `saveSort` widget requires:

- jQuery v1.4.1+
- `$.tablesorter.storage` utility which is also included in the `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js`. I mention this in case the file was modified some how.
- A browser that supports localStorage, or cookies (fallback method if localStorage is not supported).
- The save sort can be enabled/disabled using the widget option

  ```
  $(function(){
    $("table").tablesorter({
      widgets: ["saveSort"],
      widgetOptions : {
        // if false, the sort will not be saved for next page reload
        saveSort : false
      }
    });
  });
  ```